# How to resize QGraphicsView properly?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview

I try to create a simple application with `QGraphicsView`. The application can load graphical files with different ratios in the view. I would like to implement the following feature: on the application window resize, the content of the view should be also resized and centered. I do not know this part of the Qt well, so I can resize the content, but I cannot center it. How can I fix it?

`MainWindow.h` snippet:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override;

public slots:
    void onButtonClicked();

private:
    bool m_flag = false;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *m_item = nullptr;
    QGraphicsView *m_view = nullptr;
    QPixmap m_pixmap;
};
```

`MainWindow.cpp`:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto central = new QWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(central);

    // layouts
    auto mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
    central->setLayout(mainLayout);

    // top layout
    auto topLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    topLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
    mainLayout->addLayout(topLayout);
    auto btn = new QPushButton(this);
    btn->setText("Test");
    connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onButtonClicked);
    topLayout->addWidget(btn);

    m_view = new QGraphicsView;
    mainLayout->addWidget(m_view);
    auto scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    m_view->setScene(scene);
    m_view->setMinimumSize(800, 600);
    m_view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    m_view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

    QString name = ":/pic1.jpg";
    m_pixmap = QPixmap{ name }.scaled(800, 600, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    m_item = scene->addPixmap(m_pixmap);
    m_view->viewport()->resize(m_pixmap.size());
}

void MainWindow::onButtonClicked()
{
    m_flag = !m_flag;
    QString name = m_flag ? ":/pic2.png" : ":/pic1.jpg";
    m_pixmap = QPixmap{ name }.scaled(m_view->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    m_item->setPixmap(m_pixmap);
    m_view->fitInView(m_item, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
    m_view->fitInView(m_item, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
}
```

Test result for the `pic2.png`:
[image: Test result for the <code>pic2.png</code>]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an image is scaled, it is done with respect to the top left, so it will always look up if the height is smaller than the prefix or to the right if the width is smaller.

The solution is to repaint the scaled QPixmap in the middle of the final QPixmap.

```
const QSize pixmap_size{800, 600};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto central = new QWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(central);

    // layouts
    auto mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
    central->setLayout(mainLayout);

    // top layout
    auto topLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    topLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
    mainLayout->addLayout(topLayout);
    auto btn = new QPushButton(this);
    btn->setText("Test");
    connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onButtonClicked);
    topLayout->addWidget(btn);

    m_view = new QGraphicsView;
    mainLayout->addWidget(m_view);
    auto scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    m_view->setScene(scene);
    m_view->setMinimumSize(pixmap_size);
    m_view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    m_view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    m_pixmap = QPixmap(pixmap_size);
    m_pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
    m_item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem;
    m_view->scene()->addItem(m_item);
    show();
    onButtonClicked();
}

QPixmap MainWindow::createPixmap(const QString & filename, const QSize & size) const{

    QPixmap tmp = QPixmap{ filename }.scaled(size, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    QPixmap pixmap(size);
    pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter p(&pixmap);
    QPoint point(QRect({}, size).center()-tmp.rect().center());
    p.drawPixmap(point, tmp);
    p.end();
    return pixmap;
}

void MainWindow::onButtonClicked()
{
    QString name = m_flag ? ":/pic2.png" : ":/pic1.jpg";
    m_item->setPixmap(createPixmap(name, pixmap_size));
    m_flag = !m_flag;
    m_view->fitInView(m_item, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
    m_view->fitInView(m_item, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot! It seems to work! I played a little with the code and have a question. Could you please explain why the line `show();` in the constructor is important? I tried to comment it out or swap with the next line (`onButtonClicked();`) and the application broke a little bit.

Comment: @LexSergeev 
Even if you indicate size, shape, color, etc., these characteristics do not apply immediately, but when necessary, in your case the viewport of QGraphicsView is updated when they are displayed. If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, that is the best way to thank. If you do not know how to do it, check the [tour]

Comment: Of course, the answer helps me, but I do not understand how it works. It is not clear, for example, why the order is important. Of course, I know how to mark an answer, thanks for your note and the tour reference. But at the moment the answer is quite obscure.

Comment: @LexSergeev The order is important because it is necessary that the parameters of the views are established. As I said in my previous comment, Qt for reasons of efficiency do not apply the changes immediately, for example, you are indicating that you change size, do you think you can update the size when the view is not yet displayed, so you are going to change size if it still does not have size, what Qt does is save the desired size and use it when necessary.

Comment: @LexSergeev [cont]  in this case in the showEvent () method, so after executing that line you just see the correct size, I call show (), to force the call of showEvent (), just when the change is updated it can be drawn correctly.